# Using interface hides the exception thrown by implementation

Tags: java, exception, interface, implementation

Given the following code:

```java
interface Provider
{
    String getStuff();
}

class CustomProvider implements Provider
{
    public String getStuff() throws RuntimeException
    {
        // possibly throwing an exception

        return "some stuff";
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.test(new CustomProvider());
    }

    public void test(Provider provider)
    {
        provider.getStuff(); // we don't know that this can throw an exception!
    }
}
```

In this particular case we know it but may not in another situation.

How can we protect from the situation where an implementation of an interface throws an unchecked exception but the client method doesn't know the specific implementation of the interface?

It seems that sometimes with unchecked exceptions you can actually never know if calling a method can throw an exception or not.

A solution could be change the signature of the method in the interface:

```java
interface Provider
{
    String getStuff() throws Exception;
}
```

This will ensure that the clients of that method will be advised that an exception can be thrown in all implementations. The problem with this is that maybe none of the implementations of the interface will actually throw an exception. Also putting a "throws Exception" in each method of an interface looks a bit weird.

Comment: Good question, but fairly opinion based for the exact reasons you state.

Comment: That's the thing about runtime exceptions: they're not checked. This is why there's documentation--it's the only way to communicate the possibility of an RTE. Not only can an actual `RTE` be thrown, but a subclass of it may be thrown as well.

Comment: I think putting `throws AnyUncheckedException` anywhere is a bit weird.

Comment: This is pretty much the _point_ of having unchecked exceptions.  They're supposed to be unrecoverable exceptions that it's not worth bothering catching or anything because they're unrecoverable and reflect a programming error.  This is 100% working as intended: you don't need to know if a method throws an unchecked exception because there's not supposed to be anything you could do about it anyway.

Comment: You can do either and it's fine but in general if you're considering adding it to the interface you should question why you're adding it and why you want every implementation to have to take into account.  It's like declaring that every implementation should expect the unexpected.  If you really need it, go for it, but if you're substituting for a design flaw in how it will be used you should reconsider the purpose of the interface.

Comment: @DaveNewton But where should be documented? That's my question. If you put it in the class that implements the interface, the client doesn't see it because it's using the interface directly (doesn't know that's the specific implementation). So you have to put it in the documentation of the interface. But how do you know if the implementations will throw an exception or not? That's implementation details, the interface cannot/should not know that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I disagree. You can (and I think you should) catch unchecked exceptions (any kind in fact) to add more information to the context where it happens wrapping them in another exception. After that you have to rethrow it in order to let it go up. But in order to do that first you have to know that an exception can be thrown by the method. So how can you know it in the given situation?

Comment: @Mauricio In the documentation of the class(es) being used.

Comment: @mabeechen I was just saying that in order to inform the clients that an exception can be thrown, one possible solution (if not the only one) would be declaring it in the interface but for me that's not a correct solution, it's more like a hack due to the language design. Interfaces should not declare that a method can throw an exception because that's implementation details. What would you do in this case to inform the clients that the method can throw an exception when using an interface?

Comment: Ultimately this is an opinion/design issue. The checked exception argument would be that the interface should declare a domain-specific checked exception that RTEs would be wrapped up in. The unchecked exception argument says that documentation is the place to... well, document.

Comment: @DaveNewton Do you mean in the classes that implement the interface? Then the clients wouldn't know that an exception can be thrown by calling such method in a situation like this. They could get an exception without knowing why. And even worse, they won't implement a try/catch/finally to handle that exception.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not in favor of the checked exception solution. From my point of view there is no correct way to solve this problem. I don't think documentation can solve the issue in this particular situation because the clients don't have access to the documentation where the unchecked exception is declared.

Comment: @Mauricio That's the developer's fault, both on the implementation and usage side. If the implementor doesn't document, or the user doesn't read the docs, there's nothing you can do. I'd say the onus is on the implementor to provide (a) usable docs (e.g., Javadocs) and (b) enough information in the exception to guide the user. This isn't rocket science, it's simple responsibility. You're going in circles now: unchecked exceptions, by definition, rely on information in docs and/or exceptions.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm sorry but I fail to see how documentation can solve this problem. Could you tell me where to put the documentation in the example code that I posted? Thanks

Comment: @Mauricio In the Javadocs? In the usage notes? *Documentation*.

Comment: @DaveNewton I will be more specific this time to avoid confusion. Can you tell me in which line of the code that I provided would you put such documentation? What would that documentation say? In fact I invite you to provide the full code of the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Mauricio ... In the Javadocs of the implementing class method that may throw the exception. Looks like around line 8. You know, Javadocs.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know what Javadocs are, but in a situation like this the clients wouldn't have access to that documentation since they use the interface and not the concrete implementation. You can write as much documentation as you want in the implementing class but the client won't see it and therefore fail to protect the method call against the exception. Do you agree or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't they have documentation for classes they're using?! That makes zero sense. Blindly using implementations without knowing what they're doing seems phenomenally short-sighted at best, downright dangerous and irresponsible at worst. What you're missing is that using stuff you don't know anything about is silly. You know the options, you know the tradeoffs. You decide.

Comment: @DaveNewton Let me ask you a question. Do you see "phenomenally short-sighted, downright dangerous and irresponsible" if a method receives an object that implements an interface? (remember: program to an interface, not an implementation). Do you really think that it "makes zero sense" using an interface without knowing what is the concrete implementation (after all, that's what interfaces are for). Now, if you only know that your parameter implements that interface, where will you look to read the documentation? In the interface? In all of the implementations?

Comment: @Mauricio Programming to interfaces is normal. Not understanding the implementations you're using is silly. Interfaces are not an excuse to not understand implementations. It doesn't even make any sense: exceptions aside, implementations may do radically different things with the same methods--how is this any different? You must understand what you're using.

Comment: @DaveNewton Why would you care about the implementation when you are using an interface? Isn't that what interfaces are for, to abstract from the implementation? If in one situation you need to know details about the implementation, you should then use the concrete class instead of an interface. But in the situation that I'm describing here, imagine that you receive as a parameter an object that implements an interface (in order to not depend on a specific implementation for example, i.e. abstraction). You don't know what is the concrete class that you receive in the parameter. What do you do?

Comment: @Mauricio You *must* care about implementations because they determine *what actually happens*. Take `List` interface and `get(int)`: the difference between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` implementations have performance consequences for large lists. Let's say a library takes a `List` and uses `get`. *Your* decision on the implementation makes a difference. Or a contrived example, a file system interface defines `deleteFile` implementation, and one implementation doesn't actually delete the file but moves it to a trash directory. Why isn't file system usage going down after call `deleteFile`?

Comment: Interfaces provide a contract by name only: they cannot enforce anything else. Implementations define behavior: they are what actually *do* things. Not knowing what they do, or how they do it, is silly.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Implementations of interfaces may be written long after the calling code, and by different parties. It is not feasible in general to expect callers to know about the implementation. This is a good thing.

Comment: @AndyThomas Yes and no; it's clearly dependent on what's *actually* being discussed. Underlying changes can *very* easily cause breakage, performance issues, or downright incompatibilities *depending on what's actually happening*.

Comment: @Mauricio If it were my implementation I wouldn't include it in the signature of the interface.  It might be different if it were a base class but my opinion on exceptions is to treat them as things that shouldn't be expected instead of a mechanism for communicating an expected problem.  For the interface, I wouldn't assume that an exception might happen and trust the consumers of it to deal with it appropriately if it does.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think you are talking in the context when you write the whole application. In that case you can anticipate and predict what implementations will be used and where. But think about the context when you use code from third parties. For example, a framework that calls a method that you must implement and the parameter is not a concrete class but an interface. The framework will choose the correct implementation in runtime but you won't know it. I simplified a lot but to make my point, sometimes you don't know what is the specific implementation, leading to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that sometimes with unchecked exceptions you can actually never know if calling a method can throw an exception or not.

The compiler doesn't check unchecked exceptions. You can *document* the constraints of the interface, but they won't be automatically validated by the compiler.

You suggest declaring that the method throws Exception. A more constrained approach would be to declare that the method throws some checked exception.

For example, you could declare specifically that your method may throw an I/O exception, as shown below. Callers then need only handle or throw IOException, rather than many more possible Exceptions.

```
interface Provider
{
    String getStuff() throws IOException;
}
```

Another option is to declare an ad hoc exception type. This allows the interface to advertise an exception contract with callers, without limiting what kinds of exceptions implementations can *encounter*.

```
interface Provider
{
    String getStuff() throws ProviderException;
}

class MyProvider implements Provider {
    public String getStuff() throws ProviderException {
       try {
          ...
       } catch ( IOException e ) {
          throw new ProviderException( e );
       }
    }
}

public class ProviderException extends Exception {
    public ProviderException( Exception cause ) {
        super( cause );
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: My suggestion of declaring the exception in the interface is the only one that can warn the clients that an exception can be thrown. But I'm not in favor of that "solution" (actually more like a hack for me).

First because declaring an exception there is adding implementation details, something that the interface shouldn't do.

And second, what exception to declare? Using "Exception" becomes to broad and ambiguous. I don't agree with using "IOException" because maybe the operation has nothing to do with input output operations.

Comment: @Mauricio You have to operate within the restrictions the environment places on you. You already know the options. If there's no "correct" answer, and you already understand the solutions, it's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm aware of the restrictions of the environment. I'm just asking in case somebody can offer a better way do deal with this problem. I said that there is no "correct" way to do it in my opinion, not as a fact. I'm just looking for another approach to solve such situation, that's it.

Comment: @Mauricio - IOException was an *example* of a more precise exception. The point is that most throws clauses can be less ambiguous. **A `throws`  clause in an interface is not an implementation detail -- it's part of the public contract of the interface.** The compiler uses that public contract to validate that callers are using the method correctly. You ask how the client method can know what exceptions might be thrown, when none are declared. Check, or check not. The first informs the callers, the latter does not.

Comment: @AndyThomas An interface should declare only what are the parameters (if any) and what is the return value (if any). Declaring what exceptions can be thrown is getting into how the method is implemented and not what the method should do. When you design an interface, how can you know beforehand if the concrete classes will throw an exception or not? Let's say today you define an interface that doesn't throw any exception and all it's implementations don't throw any either. Everything is good. What if tomorrow one of the implementations must throw a checked exception?

Comment: @Mauricio - In Java, an interface [specifies a **contract about an interaction** with the outside world, and that contract is enforced by the compiler](http://bit.ly/1Qy6tJd). In Java, you can include exceptions in that contract. Sometimes you know a priori what kinds of exceptions an interface method may throw, either by context or by creating ad hoc exceptions that wrap underlying exceptions. If you want to follow your belief, you can use unchecked exceptions. If you want callers to know that an interface method can throw an exception, use a `throws` clause.

Comment: @AndyThomas I know that Java allows you to declare exceptions in the contract. I will rephrase my question: can you assume in a given situation that none of the implementations of an interface will ever throw a checked exception? If you assume that no, what if later one implementation requires it? If you assume yes, what kind of exception? What if later you need to throw one more general?

Comment: @Mauricio - It's useful to distinguish between a method implementation *throwing* and *encountering* exceptions. You can always catch an exception, wrap it in another exception that satisfies the method contract, and throw the wrapper. If the method contract does not allow any checked exceptions, you could wrap in an unchecked exception type. This is not ideal -- methods on the call stack may have no idea that exception is coming.

Comment: @AndyThomas You are right, it's no ideal (although sometimes you have no option) but for me that's more like fixing an issue by adding another one. The goal of my original question was to know if there is a clean way to warn callers about an unchecked exception since with only the interface we don't have that information. I guess in the end doing nothing will be similar as using another language that only uses unchecked exceptions where you have to rely on people writing and reading the documentation.